# WebView not loading .m3u8 streaming

Tags: android, webview

In my Android app I have this code to create and load an URL in the WebView.

```
public class TVDetail extends AppCompatActivity{

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tvdetail);

    final String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tv_link");

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tvWebView);

    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

It loads this (and I can't interact with it)

[image: Original APP webView]

This is the Logcat (I can't see anything broken)

```
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:27] Constructor
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:358] onViewFocusChanged: gainFocus [false]
D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:326] hideKeyboard
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:56] isActive: false
D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:358] onViewFocusChanged: gainFocus [true]
D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:140] onCreateInputConnection returns null.
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 6307
E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@28002dbe time:3106426950
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 6307
D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:253] updateKeyboardVisibility: type [0->0], flags [0], show [true], 
D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:326] hideKeyboard
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:56] isActive: true
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:65] hideSoftInputFromWindow
D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:253] updateKeyboardVisibility: type [0->0], flags [0], show [true], 
D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:326] hideKeyboard
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:56] isActive: true
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:65] hideSoftInputFromWindow
```

Then I created another App with the same code to try to solve the problem, but in the new App, the WebView loads correctly and I can interact with it

[image: Other APP webView]

I've been stuck with this problem for days, I have searched on the Internet but I couldn't find any possible solution to it.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Getting
 D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:140] onCreateInputConnection returns null.
I am using WebviewChromeClient to load my url. It seems to device specific. Not getting this issue on S6 but getting on Htc.

Comment: I have tried this with a Motorola and works fine in both. But I have tried the two apps (only webview and real app) in my Z5 and only works one of them. :/

Comment: Got this issue in Oppo devices also.